# Vulkan validation layers complain about extension not enabled, code works as if extension was enabled

Tags: c++, validation, vulkan

I am trying to use the dynamic rendering extension, to that effect I am initializing my instance this way:

```cpp
    auto enabled = vk::ValidationFeatureEnableEXT::eBestPractices;
    vk::ValidationFeaturesEXT features;
    features.enabledValidationFeatureCount = 1;
    features.pEnabledValidationFeatures = &enabled;

    vk::PhysicalDeviceDynamicRenderingFeaturesKHR dynamic_rendering = {};
    dynamic_rendering.dynamicRendering = true;

    features.pNext = &dynamic_rendering;

    // Setup general information about the current application.
    vk::ApplicationInfo program_info(
        "NeverEngine",
        VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0),
        "No Engine",
        VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0),
        VK_API_VERSION_1_2);
    // Create Vulkan instance to communicate with the loader.
    vk::InstanceCreateInfo create_info = {};
    create_info.pNext = &features;
    create_info.pApplicationInfo = &program_info,
    create_info.enabledLayerCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(VALIDATION_LAYERS.size()),
    create_info.ppEnabledLayerNames = VALIDATION_LAYERS.data(),
    create_info.enabledExtensionCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(required_extensions.size()),
    create_info.ppEnabledExtensionNames = required_extensions.data();

    auto [result, instance] = vk::createInstanceUnique(create_info);
    Assert(result == vk::Result::eSuccess, "Error: Failed to create instance");
```

However I am getting these errors:

```
VUID-VkInstanceCreateInfo-pNext-pNext(ERROR / SPEC): msgNum: -1337267667 - Validation Error: [ VUID-VkInstanceCreateInfo-pNext-pNext ] Object 0: VK_NULL_HANDLE, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0xb04aea2d | vkCreateInstance: pCreateInfo->pNext chain includes a structure with unexpected VkStructureType VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_DYNAMIC_RENDERING_FEATURES; Allowed structures are [VkDebugReportCallbackCreateInfoEXT, VkDebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT, VkValidationFeaturesEXT, VkValidationFlagsEXT]. This error is based on the Valid Usage documentation for version 204 of the Vulkan header.  It is possible that you are using a struct from a private extension or an extension that was added to a later version of the Vulkan header, in which case the use of pCreateInfo->pNext is undefined and may not work correctly with validation enabled The Vulkan spec states: Each pNext member of any structure (including this one) in the pNext chain must be either NULL or a pointer to a valid instance of VkDebugReportCallbackCreateInfoEXT, VkDebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT, VkValidationFeaturesEXT, or VkValidationFlagsEXT (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.3.204.1/linux/1.3-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-VkInstanceCreateInfo-pNext-pNext)
    Objects: 1
        [0] 0, type: 3, name: NULL
VUID-VkInstanceCreateInfo-pNext-pNext(ERROR / SPEC): msgNum: -1337267667 - Validation Error: [ VUID-VkInstanceCreateInfo-pNext-pNext ] Object 0: VK_NULL_HANDLE, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_INSTANCE; | MessageID = 0xb04aea2d | vkCreateInstance: Includes a pNext pointer (pCreateInfo->pNext) to a VkStructureType (VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_DYNAMIC_RENDERING_FEATURES), but its parent extension VK_KHR_dynamic_rendering has not been enabled. The Vulkan spec states: Each pNext member of any structure (including this one) in the pNext chain must be either NULL or a pointer to a valid instance of VkDebugReportCallbackCreateInfoEXT, VkDebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT, VkValidationFeaturesEXT, or VkValidationFlagsEXT (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.3.204.1/linux/1.3-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-VkInstanceCreateInfo-pNext-pNext)
    Objects: 1
        [0] 0, type: 1, name: NULL
```

My driver, headers and validation layers are the latest version `1.3.204`.

If I don;t enable layers and just run my code, things seem to work fine, I can resize my window and rendering is updated as expected. Is this a bug in the validation layers?

Some [research](https://lesleylai.info/en/vk-khr-dynamic-rendering/) suggests I should do this instead:

```
const std::vector<const char*> device_extensions = {
    VK_KHR_SWAPCHAIN_EXTENSION_NAME,
    VK_KHR_DYNAMIC_RENDERING_EXTENSION_NAME,
    VK_EXT_EXTENDED_DYNAMIC_STATE_EXTENSION_NAME,
};

 vk::PhysicalDeviceDynamicRenderingFeaturesKHR dynamic_rendering = {};
    dynamic_rendering.dynamicRendering = true;

    // Get the features of the selected device.
    vk::PhysicalDeviceFeatures device_features = phys_device.getFeatures();

    // The enabledLayerCount and ppEnabledLayerNames parameters are deprecated,
    // they should always be 0 and nullptr.
    // https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/man/html/VkDeviceCreateInfo.html
    vk::DeviceCreateInfo create_info = {};
    create_info.pNext = &dynamic_rendering;
    create_info.queueCreateInfoCount = queue_create_infos.size();
    create_info.pQueueCreateInfos = queue_create_infos.data();
    create_info.enabledLayerCount = 0;
    create_info.ppEnabledLayerNames = nullptr;
    create_info.enabledExtensionCount = device_extensions.size();
    create_info.ppEnabledExtensionNames = device_extensions.data();
    create_info.pEnabledFeatures = &device_features;
```

But this is returning the following error:

```
Message ID name: VUID-VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo-dynamicRendering-06052
Message: Validation Error: [ VUID-VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo-dynamicRendering-06052 ] Object 0: handle = 0x2357fc0, name = Logical device: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0xdf901c9e | vkCreateGraphicsPipeline: pCreateInfos[0].renderPass is VK_NULL_HANDLE but dynamicRendering is not enabled. The Vulkan spec states: If the dynamicRendering feature is not enabled, renderPass must not be VK_NULL_HANDLE (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.3.204.1/linux/1.3-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo-dynamicRendering-06052)
```

I don;t understand, I AM enabling the extension.

Following the advice in teh comments, I am seeing this:

```
vkCreateDevice(physicalDevice, pCreateInfo, pAllocator, pDevice) returns VkResult VK_SUCCESS (0):
    physicalDevice:                 VkPhysicalDevice = 0x32f85c0
    pCreateInfo:                    const VkDeviceCreateInfo* = 0x7fff0d9dbb20:
        sType:                          VkStructureType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_CREATE_INFO (3)
        pNext:                          const void* = NULL
```

Which seems to suggest the pNext is not being set properly.

Comment: Where are you setting `sType`?

Comment: The vulkan.hpp constructor sets up `sType`, `pNext`, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably need to add `VK_KHR_DYNAMIC_RENDERING_EXTENSION_NAME` to your list of `device_extensions`.  You didn't show the code that sets up that list.  The rest of it looks OK.

It isn't that unusual for a driver to go ahead and use a requested feature, even though it isn't enabled.  But since that can change from driver to driver, it is always best to enable the extensions and features you need.

Comment: I am already doing that, let me share that snippet, i forgot.

Comment: Perhaps follow up on what krOoze said and make sure that `sType` is getting set in the debugger.  I was pretty certain that `vulkan.hpp` would initialize that for you, but it is worth checking.  After looking at the validation layer code, that's about all I can see that could go wrong.  This extension is fairly new and the validation code for it is still being worked on.  But AFAICT, you shouldn't be getting this message.  The code that issues that msg did change since the SDK to emit VUID 6051 in your case, instead of 6052.  But that shouldn't affect this issue.

Comment: This is so strange, the hpp header does set the stype for you of that I am certain. I wonder if something is broken in my isntallation.

Comment: You could turn on the `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_api_dump` layer (in the same way you turn on the validation layer) and see if the pNext chain is correct on the create device call.  I think that this layer does a pretty good job of decoding the pNext chain.

Comment: Huh, this is useful, it seems it is null for some reason.

Comment: Yes something was deleting the pointer, that was the issue!